# Comparing stationary quarterly count data with low unequal sample sizes

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, count-data

I'm sorry if my terminology above is incorrect.  My samples are injury data from mother Jones mass shooting database.  I want to compare the quarterly sum of injuries between the Obama and Trump administration to test for difference in the mean of these distributions.  I am testing if in fact injuries have increased in the current administration. My aggregated quarterly data is potentially zero inflated, and my distributions are uneven in sample size.  I ran a Wilcox rank sum test and received a p value of .03.  Is that the correct test to run? Does anyone else have any other suggestions on how to compare these two samples? Perhaps monthly aggregation , it will be severely zero inflated? Any help would be appreciated.  R Code below.

```r
distribution_1 <-  c (11, 19,  0, 70, 42, 38, 16, 54, 20, 16, 99)
distribution_2 <-  c(11, 18, 0, 48, 0, 0, 11, 0, 19, 0,  12, 9, 5, 17, 
    100, 29, 7, 14, 27, 0, 6, 34, 0, 6, 0,14, 7, 68, 25, 102, 27, 0)
wilcox.test(distribution_1,distribution_2)
```

Wilcox results

```r
W = 251, p-value = 0.03684
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Comment: Relative to the Poisson distribution, these counts are hugely overdispersed. Maybe try some count data regression, or a permutation test?